# MySQL select a single record from highest join value from multiple tables with multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following tables:

**members**

This stores a list of members for our system.

```
---------------------
| member_id | name  |
---------------------
| 1         | Bob   |
---------------------
| 2         | Joe   |
---------------------
| 3         | Tom   |
---------------------
| 4         | Bill  |
---------------------
| 5         | Will  |
---------------------
```

**categories**

This stores the categories for our system. Categories are not visible to members by default. A member must have a valid licence to be able to access a category (see below).

```
----------------------
| cat_id    | name   |
----------------------
| 1         | Cat1   |
----------------------
| 2         | Cat2   |
----------------------
| 3         | Cat3   |
----------------------
```

**licences**

Stores the licences that a member has. One member can have many licences. Licences can have a life time and will expire. Once a licence expires, the member can no longer view the category.

```
------------------------------------------------------
| id    | catid   | subid | valid_from  | valid_to   |
------------------------------------------------------
| 1     | 1       | 1     | 2014-01-01  | 2020-12-01 |
------------------------------------------------------
| 2     | 1       | 2     | 1999-01-01  | 2001-01-02 |
------------------------------------------------------
| 3     | 1       | 3     | 2014-01-01  | 2020-12-01 |
------------------------------------------------------
| 4     | 1       | 4     | 1999-01-01  | 2000-01-01 |
------------------------------------------------------
| 5     | 1       | 5     | 2014-01-01  | 2020-12-01 |
------------------------------------------------------
| 6     | 2       | 1     | 2014-01-01  | 2020-12-01 |
------------------------------------------------------
| 7     | 2       | 2     | 1999-01-01  | 2001-01-02 |
------------------------------------------------------
| 8     | 2       | 3     | 2014-01-01  | 2020-12-01 |
------------------------------------------------------
| 9     | 2       | 4     | 1999-01-01  | 2000-01-01 |
------------------------------------------------------
| 10    | 2       | 5     | 2014-01-01  | 2020-12-01 |
------------------------------------------------------
| 11    | 3       | 1     | 2014-01-01  | 2020-12-01 |
------------------------------------------------------
| 12    | 3       | 2     | 2014-01-01  | 2020-12-01 |
------------------------------------------------------
```

**preferences**

The preferences table stores whether a member wishes to receive e-mails that are are sent relating to a category. The member can set a preference of '1' for 'wish to receive' or '0' for 'do not wish to receive'. A quirk is that if the member has no record (or a null value) we make an assumption that they wish to receive.

```
-----------------------------------
| id    | catid   | subid | pref  |
-----------------------------------
| 1     | 1       | 1     |  0    |
-----------------------------------
| 2     | 2       | 1     |  1    |
-----------------------------------
| 3     | 3       | 1     |  1    |
-----------------------------------
| 4     | 1       | 2     |  0    |
-----------------------------------
| 5     | 1       | 3     |  1    |
-----------------------------------
| 6     | 2       | 3     |  0    |
-----------------------------------
```

**recipients**

When an email is sent out based on a category, the recipient is logged so we don't email them more than once.

```
-----------------------------
| id    | emailid   | subid |
-----------------------------
| 1     | 1         | 1     |
-----------------------------
| 2     | 1         | 2     |
-----------------------------
```

I'm trying to write a query the fetches all members, and their related licence for a range of category IDs, their preferences and also make sure that they don't have a record in the recipients table.

In pseudo query:

```
SELECT [all members, their licence info, and preference setting]
FROM [members table]
WHERE [member doesnt exist in the recipients table for a given emailID]
```

The issue is that I need to check against multiple categoryIDs, but return just one result and only if the preference is set to 1 (or null, or doesn't exist).

So with the example data, given we are searching for categoryIDs 1,2 and 3 (A member must have a licence for at least one of these categories) and checking against emailID of 1, the only result should be for member_id 3 (Tom) with preference ID of 6 (because it's set to 1) and licence ID of 3 (because it's valid and the preference ID of 6 corresponds to it and it is set to 1). The second result should be member_id 5 (Will) as he has a licence to catids 1 and 2, he hasn't received the email with ID of 1 and he has no specific preference set.

Reason being: Members 1 and 2 are in the recipient table for emailID 1, member 2's licence has also expired, member 4's licence has expired and member 5 has their preference set to 0.

The query I've written which isn't working quite right is:

```
SELECT 
       members.member_id,
       members.name,
       licence.catid as licencedToCat,
       categories.cat_name as categoryName,
       licence.valid_from as licenceStart,
       licence.valid_to as licenceEnd,
       preferences.pref
FROM (`members`)
JOIN `licence` ON `licence`.`subid`=`members`.`member_id`
JOIN `preferences` ON `preferences`.`subid`=`members`.`member_id`
JOIN `categories` ON `categories`.`cat_id`=`licence`.`catid`
WHERE `licence`.`catid` IN (1,2,3)
   AND `start_date` <= '2014-12-16'
   AND `end_date` >= '2014-12-16'
   AND (pref='1' OR pref IS NULL)
   AND `members`.`member_id` NOT IN (SELECT subid FROM `recipients` WHERE `recipients`.`emailid`='1')
GROUP BY `licence`.`subid`
```

The issue is that the query is returning results saying users have a preference set to 1 where they actually don't even have a record set for that category.

The desired output is any member(s) along with the licence they have for the category but only if their preference for that category is 1/null/doesn't exist AND only if they don't appear in the recipients table for a given emailID.

So, if a member has 2 licences

I appreciate this was a long read, so thanks if you're still here! Any ideas on how to tweak my query to solve this?

Comment: OK. Other things that make it a pain to reproduce your issue: Inconsistencies in how the tables are named in the query vs the description, e.g. "license" is misspelled, members.email column is not given...

Comment: After loading your tables into SQL Fiddle and correcting the inconsistencies between the query and the DDL, I'm getting an empty set result. I think your MCVE needs more work here. Try putting it together yourself in an isolated environment.

Comment: There's a discrepancy in your results. You said member 5 has their preference set to 0 but that's not true. They don't have a preference at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of your problem here is that you're using all inner joins. Like you said, a user may not have a preference, so a row may not be returned in your query. That being said, it seems like you want to inner join most tables, as it appears you only want members who have licenses, but you want to see all licenses regardless of whether that user has a preference. So, I made preferences an outer joined table:

```
SELECT m.*, l.catid AS licenseCat, c.name AS categoryName, 
  l.valid_from AS licenseStart, l.valid_to AS licenseEnd, p.pref AS preference
FROM members m
JOIN licenses l ON l.subid = m.member_id
JOIN categories c ON c.cat_id = l.catid
LEFT JOIN preferences p ON p.catid = c.cat_id AND p.subid = l.subid;
```

Once I had done that, I wrote the subquery that pulled the member_id of all members who are in the recipients table with the specified email:

```
SELECT subid
FROM recipients
WHERE emailid = 1;
```

Now you can insert that into your original query, and add your other requirements:

```
SELECT m.*, l.catid AS licenseCat, c.name AS categoryName, 
  l.valid_from AS licenseStart, l.valid_to AS licenseEnd, IFNULL(p.pref, 0) AS preference
FROM members m
JOIN licenses l ON l.subid = m.member_id
JOIN categories c ON c.cat_id = l.catid
LEFT JOIN preferences p ON p.catid = c.cat_id AND p.subid = l.subid
WHERE c.cat_id IN (1, 2, 3) AND
  l.valid_from <= '2014-12-06' AND l.valid_to >= '2014-12-06' AND
  m.member_id NOT IN (SELECT subid FROM recipients WHERE emailid = 1)
  AND (p.pref = 1 OR p.pref IS NULL);
```

You said in your question that this should return member_id 3 (which is Tom) but that does not match your results because member 5 has no preferences, so we should assume they want an email right? I'm also not sure how to group this for you. If a member has multiple subscriptions, which one do you want to keep?

I built an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59e5c/11) and tested what I have and it's really close. I hope this can at least push you in the right direction and I will edit the answer as needed.

**EDIT**

The following will give you what you want, but it is not always recommended. If you *really* don't care about the subscription dates (as long as it meets the criteria in the where clause) and you *really* don't care about the category for the user, just add `GROUP BY m.member_id` to get one row for each member.

Comment: You're quite right, member 5 should also receive the e-mail in this case. I've edited the original question. The point you raised about a member having multiple subscriptions, it should ignore any that are not valid from the date (which your query takes care of), and then it can return any of the remaining ones as long as it is valid by date. As the query is making sure that the preference attached to a subscription is either 1 or null, it doesn't matter which we get back. Does that help?

Comment: That does help. One more question (for now): In the above example, two rows are returned for Will because he has subscriptions for different categories. Do you want to see both rows, since there are multiple categories?

Comment: No, there should be only one record ever returned for any given member. As there is an active licence with either a preference explicitly set to 1 (or it is not present), it doesn't even matter which is returned.

Comment: @user972370 see the edit for an explanation on grouping, and here is an updated [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59e5c/22).

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it does the job!

Answer (score 0):

So, the final query is like these, tested and working:

```
SELECT 
       m.member_id,
       m.email,
       l.catid as licencedToCat,
       c.cat_name as categoryName,
       l.valid_from as licenceStart,
       l.valid_to as licenceEnd,
       COALESCE(p.pref, 1) pref
FROM members m
JOIN licence l ON l.subid = m.member_id
JOIN categories c ON c.cat_id = l.catid
LEFT JOIN preferences p ON p.subid= m.member_id AND p.cat_id = l.cat_id
LEFT JOIN recipients r ON r.subid = m.member_id
WHERE l.catid IN (1,2,3)
   AND start_date <= '2014-12-16' AND end_date >= '2014-12-16'
   AND COALESCE(p.pref, 1) = 1
   AND COALESCE(r.emailid, 0) = 0-- assuming with emailid = 0 it remains valid as recipient
GROUP BY m.member_id
```

However, for the purpose of the query it should only have `DISTINCT m.*` in the `SELECT` clause which would discard the `GROUP BY`

Comment: A couple of issues, a user may have two licences for the same category. For example, if a licence has expired, a new licence can be added with valid date. Secondly, the query didn't return the right data for me. The execution time was very high and for member_id 1, it returned 98 records.

Comment: is the data for those users all there?

Comment: For the purposes of the Stack question, the data has been kept very small. In my local environment there should have been around 400 records returned but I only got 2. Actually there were 100 results, but 98 duplicates of one, and 2 of the other

Comment: There was a condition missing on the JOIN with preferences `AND p.cat_id = l.cat_id`

Comment: I added the GROUP BY @user972370, but like this you might get any license interval so why do you need it in the final result? Or why do you need the pref? Will be always 1 also

Comment: That is now returning the same data, but without the 98 duplicates. However, the data is still not correct. In the recipients table there is a record for memberID 1 which has the email id of 1 but the data is still returned for that member. Your query doesn't take into account an email ID. There can be hundreds of emails for a single category, so we're only fetching the members who dont have a record in the recipients table for a given email - not all email ids

Comment: Dude, I get what you say but your recipients table is only filtering by user, not by category. Or what am I missing?

Comment: It is returning Member 3 with Category 1 and 5 for 1 and 2. Since 5 has license and no preferences it is assumed it wants to receive... So it's working fine @user972370